# Import data from a complex website via excel vba

Tags: html, xml, excel, vba

I'm still a beginner, but I can read simple html structures.

However on the website https://stockrow.com/AAPL/financials/income/annual, I tried extracting the data into excel with **xmlhttprequest** but the source data is missing the important table with all key figures.
When I inspect the site, I can see the whole html structure.

This is the source data I get:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="57x57" 
href="/favicons/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" 
href="/favicons/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" 
href="/favicons/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" 
href="/favicons/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="60x60" 
href="/favicons/apple-touch-icon-60x60.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="120x120" 
href="/favicons/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="76x76" 
href="/favicons/apple-touch-icon-76x76.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="152x152" 
href="/favicons/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicons/favicon-196x196.png" 
sizes="196x196" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicons/favicon-96x96.png" 
sizes="96x96" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicons/favicon-32x32.png" 
sizes="32x32" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicons/favicon-16x16.png" 
sizes="16x16" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicons/favicon-128.png" 
sizes="128x128" />
<meta name="application-name" content="stockrow.com"/>
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#FFFFFF" />
<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="/favicons/mstile-144x144.png" 
/>
```

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />

<link href="https://code.cdn.mozilla.net/fonts/fira.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>

  <script src="https://cdn.ravenjs.com/3.15.0/raven.min.js"></script>
  <script>Raven.config('https://3ce523a8252c436f83c6fc423b340c0a@sentry.io/144901').install()</script>

<meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token" />
```

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="/packs/stockrow-aa9c6f09f554179248530de2e33baa9b.css" />
<script src="/packs/stockrow-a35b20c51d525016f7c7.js"></script>
<script async id="_ck_381101" src="https://forms.convertkit.com/381101?v=7"></script>
```

I didn't know how to address the problem, so I thought I'd give it a try on stack overflow.

Comment: The content of the site is presumably loaded predominantly by JavaScript, and therefore not in the initial HTML. Read up on web scraping tools.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the data that the website displays, you can actually use VBA to open an instance of IE and ask IE to scrape the data for you. It's a bit of a hack but it'll do the job.

Basically, inspect the website with your browser, and see which elements contain the data you want. In your VBA script, you can ask VBA to collect the data contained within the elements.

Answer (score 0):

A closer inspection of the page HTML would have shown you that you can download an xlsx. In fact your can simply copy the URL associated with the href of the element and pass that to URLMon to direct download.

Snippet:

```html
 <a class="button hollow expanded" href="/api/companies/AAPL/financials.xlsx?dimension=MRY&amp;section=Income Statement" target="_blank">Export to Excel (.xlsx)</a>
```

Image:

[image: Path]

The href is relative so you need to tack the host domain onto the front.

---

VBA:

```
Option Explicit

#If VBA7 And Win64 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" _
    Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" ( _
    ByVal pCaller As LongPtr, _
    ByVal szURL As String, _
    ByVal szFileName As String, _
    ByVal dwReserved As LongPtr, _
    ByVal lpfnCB As LongPtr _
    ) As Long

#Else
    Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" _
                             Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" ( _
                             ByVal pCaller As Long, _
                             ByVal szURL As String, _
                             ByVal szFileName As String, _
                             ByVal dwReserved As Long, _
                             ByVal lpfnCB As Long _
                             ) As Long

#End If

Public Const BINDF_GETNEWESTVERSION As Long = &H10
Public Const folderName As String = "C:\Users\HarrisQ\Desktop\info.xlsx" '<=Change as required

Public Sub downloadPDF()
    Dim ret As Long
    ret = URLDownloadToFile(0, "https://stockrow.com/api/companies/AAPL/financials.xlsx?dimension=MRY&amp;section=Income Statement", folderName, BINDF_GETNEWESTVERSION, 0)

End Sub
```